# Install SAML 2.x

Tags: grails, spring-security, saml-2.0, spring-saml

I am trying to install SAML as explained here:
http://sphoortia.github.io/grails-spring-security-saml/docs/guide/usage.html
But I am getting errors regarding in my spring security core dependency:

```
plugins\spring-security-core-2.0.0\src\java\grails\plugin\springsecurity\web\access\intercept\ChannelFilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSourceFactoryBean.java:80: error: cannot find symbol           map.put(new AntPathRequestMatcher(entry.getKey()), SecurityConfig.createList(value));
```

As you can see, I am using spring- security-core:2.0.0. I would say that there is a kind of conflict between the spring security core dependency of my application and that of SAML's. My BuildConfig may be found below (there are more dependencies and plugins of course, I just added the related ones)`

```
dependencies {
        compile ("org.springframework.security.extensions:spring-security-saml2-core:1.0.1.RELEASE") {
            export = false
        }
    }

    plugins {
       compile ":spring-security-core:2.0.0"
        compile ':spring-security-saml:2.0.0'

    }`
```

I see that, spring-security-saml-2.0.0 is installed, but I am having problems in the spring security core, in the spring security web classes.
May I have some help/advice on that please?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I actually found the answer. I had to exclude a dependency

```
    dependencies {
        // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes e.g.
        compile ("org.springframework.security.extensions:spring-security-saml2-core:1.0.2.RELEASE"){
            export = false
            excludes "spring-security-web"
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

I also faced the same issue and was able to solve by doing following

```
compile ("org.springframework.security.extensions:spring-security-saml2-core:1.0.1.RELEASE") {
        export = false
        excludes 'spring-security-core'
        excludes 'spring-security-web'
    }
```

Comment: @grailsDude please answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41589469/using-grails-spring-security-saml-plugin question