# Using Grails Spring Security Saml Plugin

Tags: grails, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, grails-plugin, spring-saml

I am trying to use [Grails Spring Security Saml Plugin](https://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-saml) in grails app to have single sign on functionality, I have tried hard to find any example which have explanation of the steps I need to do for adding this plugin and then testing this in my local environment using mock IDP and SP but haven't found anything beside the [Grails Spring Security Saml Plugin Documentation](http://sphoortia.github.io/grails-spring-security-saml/docs/guide/index.html) which only helps in adding the plugin in the app and configuring its different properties.

Can anyone suggest the steps how I can complete this plugin integration and test it in my local environment using mock IDP and SP?

I have added following in my BuildConfig.groovy

```
dependencies {
...
    compile ("org.springframework.security.extensions:spring-security-saml2-core:1.0.1.RELEASE") {
        export = false
        excludes 'spring-security-core'
        excludes 'spring-security-web'
    }
...
}

plugins {
...
    compile ':spring-security-saml:2.0.0'
...
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I researched a lot and following are my findings

1. [Grails Spring Security Saml Plugin](https://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-saml) internally uses [Spring Security SAML](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-saml/) plugin.
2. So it is better to use [Spring Security SAML](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-saml/) plugin directly for more flexibility.

I followed [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security-saml/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/) documentation and added plugin and its configurations to my app and now its running fine. 
The best place to start for a new person on Spring SAML in grails is [Grails SSO Sample](https://github.com/fuxiaoalex/grails-sso-sample) application which I have upgraded for Grails 2.4.3. Run this app locally and get to know about the configurations done in this application and then implement those in your application step by step.

Comment: I have done the same configuration and tried logging with SSO. only thing I have changed is afterLoginURL which works fine on the local server, but when I deploy it in staging server it keeps redirected to login page. Can you help me on this one? Good job on demo!!

Comment: @Aamir Ali In the git project example, if we hit the login url again, there is a new session which is created. The already logged in session is not used. How can we handle that?